# Loop Script from Input File

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a reference file with device names in them. For example WABEL8499IPM101. I'm using this script to set the base name (without the last 3 digits) to look at the reference file and see what is already used. If 101 is used it will create a file for me with 102, 103 if I request 2 total. I'm looking to use an input file to run it multiple times. I'm also trying to figure out how to start at 101 if there isn't a name found when searching the reference file

I would like to loop this using an input file instead of manually entering bash test.sh WABEL8499IPM 2 each time. I would like to be able to build an input file of all the names that need compared and then output. It would also be nice that if there isn't a match that it starts creating names at WABEL8499IPM101 instead of just WABEL8499IPM1.

Input file example:

```
ColumnA (BASE NAME)  ColumnB (QUANTITY)
WABEL8499IPM         2
```

Script:

```
SRCFILE="~/Desktop/deviceinfo.csv"  
LOGDIR="~/Desktop/"  
LOGFILE="$LOGDIR/DeviceNames.csv"  

# base name, such as "WABEL8499IPM"
device_name=$1
# quantity, such as "2"
quantityNum=$2

# the largest in sequence, such as "WABEL8499IPM108"
max_sequence_name=$(cat $SRCFILE | grep -o -e "$device_name[0-9]*" | sort --reverse | head -n 1)

# extract the last 3digit number (such as "108") from max_sequence_name
max_sequence_num=$(echo $max_sequence_name | rev | cut -c 1-3 | rev)

# create new sequence_name
# such as ["WABEL8499IPM109", "WABEL8499IPM110"]
array_new_sequence_name=()
for i in $(seq 1 $quantityNum);
do
cnum=$((max_sequence_num + i))
array_new_sequence_name+=($(echo $device_name$cnum))
done

#CODE FOR CREATING OUTPUT FILE HERE
#for fn in ${array_new_sequence_name[@]}; do touch $fn; done;

# write log
for sqn in ${array_new_sequence_name[@]};
 do
echo $sqn >> $LOGFILE
done
```

Usage:

```
bash test.sh WABEL8499IPM 2
```

Result in the log file:

```
WABEL8499IPM109
WABEL8499IPM110
```

Comment: Can you provide example for source file and desired output...

Comment: `while read device_name quantityNum; do bash test.sh "$device_name" "$quantityNum"; done <"input_file"` ?

Comment: Source file is listed above as "Input file example:". It's just a csv file with two columns. One for the base device name and one for the quantity needed. Output would be "Result in the log file:" with the quantity of device names made. It looks at the reference file to find whats already used and then outputs the next available in the quantity listed.

Comment: I have a reference file with device names in them. For example WABEL8499IPM101. I'm using this script to set the base name (without the last 3 digits) to look at the reference file and see what is already used. If 101 is used it will create a file for me with 102, 103 if I request 2 total. I'm looking to use an input file to run it multiple times. I'm also trying to figure out how to start at 101 if there isn't a name found when searching the reference file.

Comment: What have you try youself since your last question?

Comment: Again - Could you add some explanation to your question? Don't spread your requirements out around comments, simply [edit] your question to present all relevant information clearly and cohesively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap a loop around your code instead of assuming the args come in on the command line.

```
SRCFILE="~/Desktop/deviceinfo.csv"  
LOGDIR="~/Desktop/"  
LOGFILE="$LOGDIR/DeviceNames.csv"  

while read device_name quantityNum
do max_sequence_name=$( grep -o -e "$device_name[0-9]*" $SRCFILE |
                        sort --reverse | head -n 1)
   max_sequence_num=${max_sequence_name: -3}

   array_new_sequence_name=()
   for i in $(seq 1 $quantityNum)
   do cnum=$((max_sequence_num + i))
      array_new_sequence_name+=("$device_name$cnum")
   done

   for sqn in ${array_new_sequence_name[@]};
   do echo $sqn >> $LOGFILE
   done
done < input.file
```

I'd maybe pass the input file as the parameter now.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for some of the reasons not to take this approach.

Comment: There are certainly better ways. Suggest a few.

Comment: This is the wrong way to do anything, hence my comment, but I can't suggest a better way to do whatever it is the OP specifically wants to do since I personally don't yet understand what it is he's trying to do. Since no-one else has answered I suspect I'm not the only one. So, we're still waiting for the OP to provide all the information currently missing from his question and once he does that, **then** I expect multiple people will answer it, though too much time may have passed now for people to look back and see this is still unanswered.

Comment: Fair enough, but I am intrigued. The link you posted makes valid points, but seems to gloss over the fact that a lot of people use bash scripts because it's the quickest way to handle a problem, not because it's the right way. Yes, people certainly strain credulity with some of the things they come up with, but...   would this not work? I would certainly redesign it if I had the chance, but all I'm doing is internalizing what [Kamil Cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamil-cuk) suggested in a comment. Agreed, it's not ideal. When he comes back with more info, I can edit or delete.

Comment: The quickest way to fire a gun is to always leave the safety off and walk around with it in your hand and your finger on the trigger but I wouldn't recommend that either :-). My point is that often these "quick" shell scripts are very buggy and fail cryptically given some specific input values, or environment values, or directory contents, etc. There's nothing wrong with using shell scripts, it's just shell loops that are very rarely the right approach and when they are necessary they're very difficult to write robustly and almost impossible to write efficiently.

Comment: I don't disagree...and to continue to point out "but" anything just devolves into a philosophical argument, so suffice it to say that you are speaking truth. Cheers.